# Multiply computed value by an edit box value

Tags: javascript, xpages

My main goal is to Multiply two fields and and show/save the answer in another computed field (the mileage field). I want to multiply a computed field totalKM (not in a form) by a edit box field perKM(in a form) defaulted to .52.

I have appended the table below with all the fields for convenience.

```
<xp:table>
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:label value="Mileage:"
                id="mileage_Label1" for="mileage1">
            </xp:label>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:text escape="true" id="mileage">
                <xp:this.converter>
                    <xp:convertNumber type="number"></xp:convertNumber>
                </xp:this.converter>
                <xp:this.value>
                    <![CDATA[#{javascript:return claimDoc.getItemValue("perKM");}]]>
                </xp:this.value>
            </xp:text>
        </xp:td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </xp:tr>
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:label value="Total KM" id="label1"></xp:label>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:text escape="true" id="totalKM"
                style="font-weight:bold">
                <xp:this.value>
                    <![CDATA[#{javascript:var cView:NotesView = database.getView("expenses");
                        var nav:NotesViewNavigator = cView.createViewNav();

                        var entry:NotesViewEntry = cView.getEntryByKey((@Name("[CN]",context.getUser().getDistinguishedName())),true);
                        entry = nav.getPrev(entry);
                        if (entry == null ) {
                        //donothing
                        }
                        else {
                            return entry.getColumnValues()[2];
                            }   }]]>
                </xp:this.value>
            </xp:text>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td>
            by
            <xp:inputText id="inputText1"
                style="width:30px" value="#{claimDoc.perKM}"
                defaultValue=".52">
                <xp:this.converter>
                    <xp:convertNumber type="number"></xp:convertNumber>
                </xp:this.converter>
            </xp:inputText>
            cents
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td>
        </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
</xp:table>
```

Comment: If you use a managed bean or POJO, you can bind your fields to the bean, and then put your code in the results fields getter method.  Use a onChange event to update the resulting field.  (Best to put the field in a container and update the container.)  You will need a basic knowledge of java to do this.  I wrote a blog post that might help you: http://notesspeak.blogspot.com/2013/06/dynamic-computed-values-in-xpage.html

Comment: Steve put your comment in an answer so it can be accepted. I would use Java too, but it might work with a SsJS object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this through the use of java and managed beans.  This isn't the only way you can do it, but I would venture the best way.

You should bind your fields to the managed bean directly, like this:
[image]

Make the fields using the Edit Box (even for the result which isn't editable)

In your managed java bean, for the value you want to automatically compute do something like this:
[image]

1. Delete or comment out the 'setter'
2. Put the code that calculates the result in the 'getter'
3. Because you commented out the setter, the resulting field is not editable

The last thing you will need to do is to create a partial update to refresh the container that holds the field you want to compute.  It can be in the same or a different container as the editable fields.

---

Here is a link to a blog post I wrote describing how I implemented this:  http://notesspeak.blogspot.com/2013/06/dynamic-computed-values-in-xpage.html

If you haven't used managed beans or java before it, it is well worth investing your time to watch this two hour class on managed beans from Connect 2013.  Russ Maher is a great teacher.  http://ibmtvdemo.edgesuite.net/software/lotus/connect_2013/01-Sunday/JMP402/JMP402.html

There are also a lot of blog posts out there, as well as Notes in 9 videos.

Comment: Your answer is great thanks for all the background! That video is great.

Comment: Glad that you found it helpful.  Once you go down this path, it will change the way (for the better) that you think about xpages.  Along the same lines, this post is a good read: http://www.timtripcony.com/blog.nsf/d6plinks/TTRY-955KHF

Comment: I have to admit that at first I looked at your answer and thought "that's crazy and dumb" but after seeing the video I see that with a bit of extra set up I can get exactly what I was looking for in the beginning (which was var * var = field). Plus I already know java so BAM!

Comment: I thought it was 'crazy and dumb' at first too.  I forced myself to take the leap based on the advice of those I trusted.  That video also helped me a ton as well.  Glad that you got it working!